# setting a default value for an angular directive property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that has an optional "label" for a button - if this label is not supplied, I want it to have a default value

this is the directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myButton',function(){

    var ctrl = function ($scope) {
        var controller = this;

        controller.label = controller.label || 'Save';

        console.log("label=",controller.label);
    };

    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',

        scope: {
            label: '@?',
        },

        templateUrl: 'directives/myButton.html',

        controller: ctrl,
        controllerAs: 'controller',
        bindToController: true,
    };
});
```

the html in the template is this

```
<md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button class="md-raised">{{controller.label}}</md-button>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

and I am calling the directive like this

```
<my-button label="fooBar"></my-button>
```

this works - and I see the label "fooBar" on the button, and 'label=fooBar' on the console

however, if I don't supply the label

```
<my-button></my-button>
```

The button has no label, but I see 'label=Save' on the console

what am I missing ?

thanks

Comment: Seems to be working as expected in this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/R7BmHJ3dGKU5Vz6s5T0H?p=preview  I used template instead of templateUrl but not sure how that should change things.

Comment: yeah - it does - I can't understand why it doesn't work in my app. I've used the compile option (see accepted answer) and that did work though. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `compile` method on the directive to achieve the desired result, a little example

```
.directive('my-bytton', [ function() {
    ...
    compile: function(element, attrs){
       if (!attrs.attrOne) { attrs.attrOne = 'default value'; }
       if (!attrs.attrTwo) { attrs.attrTwo = 'default value2'; }
    },
        ...
  }
});
```